# IAP - how to list individual transaction id's in itunes connect

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

We have developed an app for iphone and registered some products for in-app payments. due to some technical errors, some of our customers complained that even they bought a certain product they can't get the content they payed for. We did some digging and found out a bug in our code that would indeed prevent some transactions to register in our servers. Now we have angry customers who demands the content they bought. We are willing to do that, the only problem is how can we check if the said user is really effected by this bug? We figured we could ask the user for the transaction id and check it in itunes connect. In android, google play offers the orderid for each transaction for you to compare. But I couldn't find any such information in itunes connect. basically i would need a transaction list which has the information productid, orderid/transactionid and date of purchase. is it available throught itunes connect or some other way like web service or is apple hiding these data from us beucase of "privacy"?

Comment: how about fixing the bug and using "restore purchases"?

Comment: Bug is fixed already. But the in-app purchases were consumable, so no restore for those i believe.

Comment: hey @VolkanUlukut were you able to find any info on your users who purchased an IAP?

Comment: nope. apple is very strict about "user privacy" in a way which prevents his users to be refunded.